# Should I remove leak canary code/classes for release build?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, release, leakcanary

I searched for an answer to this and couldn't find anything, which probably means it's a basic question.  At the risk of showing my ignorance, I'm going to ask anyway.  I am preparing my app for release and want to insure Leak Canary doesn't popup for my users.  My leak canary related dependencies are as such.

```
dependencies {
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
}
```

I think that since the releaseCompile contains `no-op` it means I can proceed with my release build as is without removing the Leak Canary code.  Am I right?

Comment: AFAIK, you are correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this online.

```
dependencies {
// Real LeakCanary for debug builds only: notifications, analysis, etc
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'

// No-Op version of LeakCanary for release builds: no notifications, no analysis, nothing
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
}
```

Comment: why add no-op if it does nothing?

Comment: @farhanpatel Because even if it does nothing, you still need to have the classes to compile your app

Comment: @ysfcyln But there are no classes needed, only the dependency import.

Answer (score 5):

The answers are correct but there's an [updated and easier solution](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/) as of 4/13/19:

```
    dependencies {
      debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'
    }
```

no need for no-ops nor proguard.

but [why?](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/979)

ok but [how?](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/faq/#how-does-leakcanary-get-installed-by-only-adding-a-dependency)

Comment: Version in June 2020 is:  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4'

Comment: **And what happens if you use even a single Leak-canary API**, like to exclude a known leak, is that, you need to create a no-op class manually.

Answer (score 3):

I was using the latest version of the library 2.0-alpha-1 in debug mode, and I didn't find the release dependency of the library.
I did the following:

1. I created separate folders for each build mode **(release and debug)**
2. The path of the debug folder: **app/src/debug**
3. The path of the release folder: **app/src/release**

Then I created a class for initializing leak canary called **LeakCanaryInitializer.kt** (I created it inside the two build folders)

- debug: **app/src/debug/java/LeakCanaryInitializer.kt**
- release: **app/src/release/java/LeakCanaryInitializer.kt**

The class in the **release** mode contains:

```
import android.content.Context
object LeakCanaryManager {

  fun init(context: Context) {
    // We should do nothing in the release mode
  }
}
```

The class in the **debug** mode contains:

```
import android.content.Context
import leakcanary.LeakCanary
import leakcanary.LeakSentry

object LeakCanaryManager {

  fun init(context: Context) {
    // Here you should write your custom initializing
  }
}
```

Then in your Application class call the init method:

```
LeakCanaryManager.init(this)
```

My gradle file only contains the debug dependency:

```
debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-1"
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I am facing the exact same issue as they dropped the `no-op` package for `leak canary 2` thus the classes are not available for all build flavors.

Comment: Hey this didn't seem to work for me. @Francois any help?

Comment: Send me a pm and we can look at resolving your issue. Are you upgrading to leak canary 2? Also what errors are you getting?